# Improve precision in solution for Sylvester equation with python (scipy)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to solve numerically the following Sylvester equation (eq. (11) from [arXiv:1906.08808](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.08808))

[image: Sylvester equation]

where W+ is defined as exp(K*t). I have defined the following function to compute V(t) at a given time t.

**Edited** (after comment from [Warren Weckesser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59376329/improve-precision-in-solution-for-sylvester-equation-with-python-scipy#comment104950528_59376329))

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import expm, solve_sylvester

def covariance_matrix(K, V0, D, t, precision=precision):
    """
    It computes the covariance matrix at time t.

    See eq. (11) in arXiv:1906.08808
    """
    Wp = expm(K*t)
    WpT = Wp.transpose()
    KT = K.transpose()
    C = -D + K @ Wp @ V0 @ WpT + Wp @ V0 @ WpT @ KT + Wp @ D @ WpT
    return solve_sylvester(K, KT, C)
```

However, it is not working as expected. For example, if I call the function with t=0, I don't recover the initial V0 as it should (see screenshot below)

[image: Screenshot Jupyter notebook]

This looks like some kind of numerical error. I have tried different precisions (`np.float64` and `np.float128`) but I don't see any difference. My guess is that the precision is lost when using expm from `scipy.linalg`.

Any ideas how to change this code to get better precision?

**Expanded** (also after edition)

The problem with these small errors (order of 1e-13 at time 0) is that later I am using this matrix to compute some quantity that is very sensible to this little differences.

I leave here the exact code that I am using later with this matrix.

```py
def entanglement(V):
    """
    It gives the logarithmic negativity computed from the covariance matrix.
    See: Phys. Rev. A 65, 032314 (2002) for details.
    """
    Ia = V[:2, :2]
    Ib = V[2:, 2:]
    L  = V[:2, 2:]
    s = det(Ia) + det(Ib) - 2 * det(L)
    v = np.sqrt((s - np.sqrt(s**2 - 4 * det(V))) / 2)
    ent = -np.log2(2*v)
    if ent > 0:
        return ent
    else:
        return 0
```

**Minimal, reproducible example**

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import expm, det, solve_sylvester

precision = np.float128

def drift_matrix(w, eta, Q):
    return np.array([[0,           w,    0,        0],
                     [-w*(1-eta), -w/Q, -w*eta,      0],
                     [0,           0,    0,        w],
                     [-w*eta,      0, -w*(1-eta), -w/Q]], dtype=precision)

def init_covariant_matrix(n, s=0):
    return np.diag(np.ones(4, dtype=precision) * (n + 1/2) * np.cosh(2*s))

def diagonal_matrix(n, w, Q):
    return np.diag(np.array([0,1,0,1], dtype=precision) * w/Q * (1 + 2*n))

def covariance_matrix(K, V0, D, t):
    Wp = expm(K*t)
    WpT = Wp.transpose()
    KT = K.transpose()
    C = -D + K @ Wp @ V0 @ WpT + Wp @ V0 @ WpT @ KT + Wp @ D @ WpT
    return solve_sylvester(K, KT, C)

w = precision(0.1)
eta = precision(1.36e-6) / w**2
n = precision(0)
Q = precision(1e4)
K = drift_matrix(w, eta, Q)
V0 = init_covariant_matrix(n, 1.73)
D = diagonal_matrix(n, w, Q)
V0_1 = covariance_matrix(K, V0, D, 0)

# What I want (ideally)
np.all(np.abs(V0 - V0_1) < np.finfo(np.float128).resolution)

# I would still be happy if...
np.all(np.abs(V0 - V0_1) < np.finfo(np.float64).resolution)
```

Comment: You say "W+ is defined as exp(K*t)", but the code shows `Wp = expm(K)`.  Should that be `Wp = expm(K*t)`?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct, thanks for noticing that. That was a small typo when I wrote the function to make the post here. But the issue remains. I will edit the question with the fix code and modified screenshot.

Comment: It might be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Okay, I will read that link and I will prepare one. For the moment I have edited and expanded a bit the original post.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I have added a minimal, reproducible example at the end of the post. Hope it helps clarify my issue.